# HTML5 audio reference

Tags: html

HTML5 has a good support for audio and video playback and control.
The official HTML5 reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/

I've seen in some web pages that the audio object has the play() and pause() functions, also an attribute called "currentTime", and many more things.

However, "play", "pause" and "currentTime" is not even documented in the official HTML5 reference.
Where can I find a full reference of HTML5 audio?

Best regards,
David

Answer (score 5, accepted):

play(), pause() etc come from HTMLMediaElement interface, documented here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html#htmlmediaelement

Answer (score 1):

Ajaxian has [a decent reference](http://ajaxian.com/archives/html5-media-support-video-and-audio-tags-and-scriptability) that I use for my Google Chrome extension audio player. There's not much there because there's not much to it. :) It also points to some other references.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_audio_and_video_in_Firefox is also a good references. The standard will ultimately needs to be what is supported by at least two browsers.